# Modify Solr Query by adding additional filters in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I'm trying to add custom filters to the query (TYPO3 v10, EXT:solr 11.2). However, this doesn't want to work.

After I simplified the use-case significantly and debugged it, I'm still not further, but rather more confused.

---

Filter works, if added via TypoScript:

```
plugin.tx_solr {
  search {
    filter {
      jobTitle = title:Dev*
    }
  }
}
```

The same filter added via `modifySearchQuery`-hook does *not* work:

```
public function modifyQuery(Query $query)
{
    $filterQuery = new FilterQuery([
        'key' => 'jobTitle2',
        'value' => 'title:Dev*',
    ]);
    return $query->addFilterQuery($filterQuery);
}
```

When debugging the query, both filters look the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Guido, who hit me on the right point: sometimes, keys are keys.

In the hook, the array-keys for `FilterQuery` have to be `key` and `query` (not `value`, as I've used)

```
public function modifyQuery(Query $query)
{
    $filterQuery = new FilterQuery([
        'key' => 'jobTitle2',
        'query' => 'title:Dev*', // <-- correct key
    ]);
    return $query->addFilterQuery($filterQuery);
}
```